# mySql copy rows into same table with key value changed (not overwriting existing)

Tags: mysql, copy

How do I copy a selection of rows from a mySql table and insert with just the key value changed. Can I do a select and insert in same query?

To be precise, what I want would look like this:

Table cols, ID and ISO3 are keys:

```
+----+------+-------------------------+
| ID | ISO3 |          Text           |
+----+------+-------------------------+
|  1 | ENU  | A text in english       |
|  2 | ENU  | Another text in english |
|  3 | ENU  | bla bla                 |
|  1 | JPN  | 与えられた枠             |
+----+------+-------------------------+
```

After the insert I want my table to look like this:

```
+----+------+---------------------------+
| ID | ISO3 |           Text            |
+----+------+---------------------------+
|  1 | ENU  | A text in english         |
|  2 | ENU  | Another text in english   |
|  3 | ENU  | bla bla                   |
|  1 | JPN  | 与えられた枠               |
|  2 | JPN  | Another text in english   |
|  3 | JPN  | bla bla                   |
+----+------+---------------------------+
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO your_table (ID, ISO3, TEXT) 
SELECT ID, 'JPN', TEXT
FROM your_table 
WHERE ID IN ( list_of_ id's )
```

If you want to change a value in *one cell*, just hard-type the value instead of selecting from table (like I did with **'JPN**').

Comment: Just to be clear, this is what I had: 
INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2, col3) SELECT "mynewvalue", col2, col3 FROM my_table where col2="value"

Comment: Clarifying note: You may also alias the hard typed value in the SELECT statement if you require exact column names.

Comment: What if i want to copy data with one column value to be different in all copied rows?

Answer (score 5):

If your key is auto_increment, and you have a table structure like `primary_key | col1 | col2 | col3` then you can do something along the lines of

```
INSERT INTO table (
   col1, col2, col3
) SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM table
WHERE primary_key IN(1, 2, 45, 54, 774, 4434 /* etc */);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do

```
insert into your_table (SELECT field1, field2,(changed_value_for_field3) as field3 FROM your_table where your_condition);
```